# Trying to work with curve_fit - Error: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()

Tags: python, scipy

here's the code I'm having trouble with:

```
B_mags = [12.113,7.508,2.880]
N_b = [565.4,39521,3075076.7]
V_mags = [11.326,6.404,2.869]
N_v = [1190,43511.3,2933500] 

def linear(N,A):
    return A*np.log10(N) # This is equation (4.1) in a form such that curve_fit can be applied to estimate A.

# Finding A using curve_fit:

for (a,b,c,d) in zip(V_mags,N_v,B_mags,N_b):
    print(a,b,c,d)
    Nratio = b/d
    popt,pocov = curve_fit(linear,Nratio,(a-c),p0=[-2.5])
```

Basically I'm trying to use curve_fit to find an estimate of the coefficient A in the following equation:

[image]

I'm doing this by treating it as a linear curve (over a logarithmic domain) and fitting it with curve_fit, where my y variable is (m_1-m_2) and my x variable is Nratio = N_1/N_2.

When I try and run this through curve_fi I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-9ecbf5ef33e3> in <module>
     12     print(a,b,c,d)
     13     Nratio = b/d
---> 14     popt,pocov = curve_fit(linear,Nratio,(a-c),p0=[-2.5])

/local/environments/default/default-venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0, sigma, absolute_sigma, check_finite, bounds, method, jac, **kwargs)
    784         res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
    785         popt, pcov, infodict, errmsg, ier = res
--> 786         ysize = len(infodict['fvec'])
    787         cost = np.sum(infodict['fvec'] ** 2)
    788         if ier not in [1, 2, 3, 4]:

TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue is with `Nratio`. You need to make that an array-like. Reference: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

Comment: Let me see if I understand this correctly - you try to use curve fit with a single data point? Where is the curve that you try to fit?

Comment: Yep, that was the problem - I was using a loop for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a curve-fitting problem.  To do curve fitting, you have one independent variable and one dependent variable.  Where are those?  Your equation is really A (the unknown) = (m1-m2) / log10(N1/N2).  That's fine, but you can't really have a curve with 4 independent variables.  It would be a 5-dimensional surface.  ;)

Here are the values for A:

```
def A(dm, Nr):
    return dm / math.log10(Nr)

for (a,b,c,d) in zip(V_mags,N_v,B_mags,N_b):
    Nratio = b/d
    print( a, b, c, d, A((a-c),Nratio) )
```

Here are the results:

```
11.326 1190 12.113 565.4 -2.4350913766428923
6.404 43511.3 7.508 39521 -26.42783688627219
2.869 2933500 2.88 3075076.7 0.5373754369759042
```

So what does A depend on here?  What are you "curving" A against?  Which knob are we turning?